# Insert element between other elements of array if condition is met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dayjs

Now I have an array like below.

```
  const reserveList = [
    { name: 'john', start: '2022-09-01' },
    { name: 'mark', start: '2022-09-02' },
    { name: 'ken', start: '2022-09-03' },
    { name: 'sara', start: '2022-09-05' },
  ];
```

and I want to add empty object if there is empty day between two days like below.

```
  const reserveList = [
    { name: 'john', start: '2022-09-01' },
    { name: 'mark', start: '2022-09-02' },
    { name: 'ken', start: '2022-09-03' },
    {},
    { name: 'sara', start: '2022-09-05' },
  ];
```

here is my code(it doesn't work). Is it possible to make it work using `map` or other ways?

```
  const newList = (reserveList: Array<any>) => {
    reserveList.map((reserve, index) => {
      dayjs(reserveList[index + 1].start).diff(
        dayjs(reserveList[index].start, 'day') > 1
      ) && reserveList.splice(index + 1, 0, {});
    });
  };
```

Comment: If there are two days difference, set two empty objects? and so on?

Comment: one empty object for days difference!(sorry I didn't explain it) @Mina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can `reduce` method instead of `map`, because `map` is desigened to manipulate each item not add or delete items from the array.
2. The `days.js` condition is wrong, this is the  correct syntax.

```
dayjs(reserveList[index + 1].start).diff( 
    reserveList[index].start, "day"
)> 1
```

```js
const reserveList = [
    { name: "john", start: "2022-09-01" },
    { name: "mark", start: "2022-09-02" },
    { name: "ken", start: "2022-09-03" },
    { name: "sara", start: "2022-09-05" },
];
const newList = (reserveList) => {
    return reserveList.reduce((acc, reserve, index) => {
        let dayDifference
        if (reserveList[index + 1]) {
            dayDifference = dayjs(reserveList[index + 1].start).diff(
                reserveList[index].start, "day"
            ) > 1;
        }
        dayDifference ? acc.push(reserve, {}) : acc.push(reserve);
        return acc;
    }, []);
};
console.log(newList(reserveList))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.5/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-Ot7ArUEhJDU0cwoBNNnWe487kjL5wAOsIYig8llY/l0P2TUFwgsAHVmrZMHsT8NGo+HwkjTJsNErS6QqIkBxDw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

With one line `function`

```js
const reserveList = [
    { name: "john", start: "2022-09-01" },
    { name: "mark", start: "2022-09-02" },
    { name: "ken", start: "2022-09-03" },
    { name: "sara", start: "2022-09-05" },
];
const newList = (reserveList) => reserveList.reduce((acc, reserve, index) => [...acc, reserve, ...((reserveList[index + 1] ? (dayDifference = dayjs(reserveList[index + 1].start).diff(reserveList[index].start, "day") > 1) : null) ? [{}] : []),],[]);

console.log(newList(reserveList));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.5/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-Ot7ArUEhJDU0cwoBNNnWe487kjL5wAOsIYig8llY/l0P2TUFwgsAHVmrZMHsT8NGo+HwkjTJsNErS6QqIkBxDw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below examples mutate the `reserveList` in place.

### Vanilla JS:

```
let i = 0;
while(true)
{
    let currStartDate = new Date(reserveList[i].start)
    let currEndDate = new Date(reserveList[i+1].start)
    let currDaysDiff = (currEndDate.getTime() - currStartDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    
    if(currDaysDiff > 1) {
        let currFlag = 0;
        while(currDaysDiff > 1) {
            reserveList.splice(i + 1 + currFlag, 0, {})
            currDaysDiff--;
            currFlag++;
        }
    }
    
    i++;
    if(i === reserveList.length - 1)
        break;
}
```

### Day.js:

```
let i = 0;
while(true)
{
    let currStartDate = dayjs(reserveList[i].start)
    let currEndDate = dayjs(reserveList[i+1].start)
    let currDaysDiff = currEndDate.dayjs(currStartDate, 'day')
    
    if(currDaysDiff > 1) {
        let currFlag = 0;
        while(currDaysDiff > 1) {
            reserveList.splice(i + 1 + currFlag, 0, {})
            currDaysDiff--;
            currFlag++;
        }
    }
    
    i++;
    if(i === reserveList.length - 1)
        break;
}
```

---

You can try it with a more complicated array:

```
const reserveList = [
    { name: 'john', start: '2022-09-01' },
    { name: 'mark', start: '2022-09-06' },
    { name: 'ken', start: '2022-09-09' },
    { name: 'sara', start: '2022-09-11' }
];
```

Result:

```
[
    { name: 'john', start: '2022-09-01' },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    { name: 'mark', start: '2022-09-06' },
    {},
    {},
    { name: 'ken', start: '2022-09-09' },
    {},
    { name: 'sara', start: '2022-09-11' }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reduce function to go through the items in the original array, and add them to a new array while also injecting empty objects if the dates differ by more than one day (86400000 milliseconds)

```js
const reserveList = [
  { name: "john", start: "2022-09-01" },
  { name: "mark", start: "2022-09-02" },
  { name: "ken", start: "2022-09-03" },
  { name: "sara", start: "2022-09-05" },
];

const oneSecond = 1000;
const oneDay = oneSecond * 60 * 60 * 24;

const newReserveList = reserveList.reduce(
  (newArr, currentItem, currentIndex) => {
    if (currentIndex !== 0) {
      const previousObject = reserveList[currentIndex - 1];
      const previousStart = new Date(previousObject.start);
      const currentStart = new Date(currentItem.start);

      const diff = Math.abs(previousStart.getTime() - currentStart.getTime());

      if (diff > oneDay) {
        newArr.push({});
      }
    }

    newArr.push(currentItem);

    return newArr;
  },

  // Initialize the 'newArr' value to be an empty array
  []
);


console.log(newReserveList)
```

Comment: @Ergis OP's answer to the comments was ambiguous. If that is the case then the modification is easy and is left as an exercise for OP

Answer (score 1):

add one empty object per any one diff days:

```
 const reserveList = [
    { name: 'john', start: '2022-09-01' },
    { name: 'mark', start: '2022-09-02' },
    { name: 'ken', start: '2022-09-03' },
    { name: 'sara', start: '2022-09-07' },
  ];

const newList = [];

 reserveList.reduce((previousValue, currentValue, index) => {
  if (index !== 0) {
      const diffDays = +currentValue.start.split('-')[2] - +reserveList[index - 1].start.split('-')[2];
      if (diffDays > 1) {
        [...Array(diffDays - 1)].forEach((item) => {
          newList.push({})
        });
      }
     }
     newList.push(currentValue)
     return previousValue
   },[]);


console.log(newList)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=14#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)

Answer (score 0):

This might Work !

```
const dayjs = require("dayjs");
const reserveList = [
  { name: "john", start: "2022-09-01" },
  { name: "mark", start: "2022-09-02" },
  { name: "ken", start: "2022-09-03" },
  { name: "sara", start: "2022-09-05" },
  { name: "amir", start: "2022-09-10" },
  { name: "Masood", start: "2022-09-13" },
];

const newList = () => {
  let editedList = [];
  for (let index in reserveList) {
    editedList.push(reserveList[parseInt(index)]);
    if (parseInt(index) <= reserveList.length - 2) {
      console.log(
        reserveList[parseInt(index) + 1].start,
        reserveList[parseInt(index)].start
      );

      let diffVal = dayjs(reserveList[parseInt(index) + 1].start).diff(
        reserveList[index].start,
        "d"
      );
      console.log(diffVal);

      if (diffVal > 1) {
        for (let j = 1; j < diffVal; j++) {
          editedList.push({});
        }
      }
    }

  }
  return editedList;
};
let editedlist = newList();
console.log(reserveList);
console.log(editedlist);
```